# Combining 3 functions into a single function using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

These are the 3 functions I want to combine into a single function using for loop.

How would this be set up?

Full Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lky7vu4/1/

I originally tried this but that didn't work for some reason.

```
  const cover = document.querySelectorAll(".jacket-left, .jacket-middle, .jacket-right");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
```

How would this be written using for loop since the other way above doesn't work by itself in the code?

```js
const load = (function makeLoad() {
  "use strict";

  function _load(tag) {
    return function(url) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        const element = document.createElement(tag);
        const parent = "body";
        const attr = "src";
        element.onload = function() {
          resolve(url);
        };
        element[attr] = url;
        document[parent].appendChild(element);
      });
    };
  }
  return {
    js: _load("script")
  };
}());

(function manageCover() {
  "use strict";

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
  }
  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket-left");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());


(function manageCover() {
  "use strict";

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
  }
  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket-middle");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());

(function manageCover() {
  "use strict";

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
  }
  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket-right");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";
  const players = [];

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }

  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(true);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (players[i] !== event.target) players[i].pauseVideo();
      }
    }

    const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
    if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
    }
  }

  function addVideo(video, settings) {
    players.push(new YT.Player(video, Object.assign({
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    }, settings)));
  }

  function init(video, settings) {
    load.js("https://www.youtube.com/player_api").then(function() {
      YT.ready(function() {
        addVideo(video, settings);
      });
    });
  }
  return {
    init
  };
}());

function loadPlayer(opts) {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper) {
    const video = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    opts.width = opts.width || 198;
    opts.height = opts.height || 198;
    opts.autoplay = 1;
    opts.controls = 1;
    opts.rel = 0;
    opts.iv_load_policy = 3;
    opts.fs = 0;
    opts.disablekb = 1;

    function paramInOpts(settings, param) {
      if (opts[param] !== undefined) {
        settings[param] = opts[param];
      }
      return settings;
    }
    const settingsParams = ["width", "height", "videoid", "host"];
    const settings = settingsParams.reduce(paramInOpts, {});
    const playerVarsParams = ["autoplay", "cc_load_policy",
      "controls", "disablekb", "end", "fs", "iv_load_policy",
      "list", "listType", "loop", "playlist", "rel", "start"
    ];
    settings.playerVars = playerVarsParams.reduce(paramInOpts, {});
    videoPlayer.init(video, settings);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
    show(wrapper);
    initPlayer(wrapper);
  }
  const cover = document.querySelector(opts.target);
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}
const playlist = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g";

loadPlayer({
  target: ".jacket-left",
  width: 277,
  height: 207
});

loadPlayer({
  target: ".jacket-middle",
  width: 277,
  height: 207
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".jacket-right",
  width: 277,
  height: 207
});


loadPlayer({
  target: ".jacketc",
  width: 600,
  height: 338,
  loop: true,
  playlist
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".alpha",
  start: 0,
  end: 280,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".beta",
  start: 0,
  end: 240,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".gamma",
  start: 0,
  end: 265,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".delta",
  start: 4,
  end: 254,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".epsilon",
  start: 0,
  end: 242,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".zeta",
  start: 0,
  end: 285,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".eta",
  start: 23,
  end: 312,
  loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".theta",
  start: 2
});
loadPlayer({
  target: ".iota"
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
 width: 936px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  background: #000000;
}
.container-top {
 position: relative;
 height: 310px;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 25px;
 border: 3px solid #0059dd;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: url("https://i.imgur.com/jEMIULl.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
 background-size: cover;
}

.v-contain{
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25px;
 width: 277px;
 background: red;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.jacket{ 
 position: relative;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: auto;
 background: url("https://i.imgur.com/fzdYu8g.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
 background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.jacket-middle {
 background-position: 0 -80px;
 background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.jacket-right {
 background-position: 0 -80px;
 background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.circle{ 
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 1px solid #0059dd;
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 transition: transform 0.1s ease 0s;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0 10px;
}

.play{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 width: 38px;
 height: 22px;
 fill: #0059dd;
}

.circle:hover {
 border: 1px solid red;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

.circle:hover .play {
 fill: red;
}

.wrap{
 position: relative;
 width: 277px;
 height: 207px;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrap iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 277px;
 height: 207px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="container-top">
        <div class="v-contain ">
          <div class="jacket jacket-left">
            <div class="circle"> <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
              <title>Play</title>
              <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap wrap-left hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="jMAShwisnQI"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-contain container-middle-video">
          <div class="jacket jacket-middle">
            <div class="circle"> <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
              <title>Play</title>
              <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap wrap-middle hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-contain container-right-video">
          <div class="jacket jacket-right">
            <div class="circle"> <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
              <title>Play</title>
              <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap wrap-right hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `Array.from(iterable, mappingFunction)` to the array-like `NodeList` returned by the `document.querySelectorAll()` to map each element and add a click listener

As `querySelectorAll()` does not return a array directly, you need to convert it to one using `Array.from()` and simultaneously apply the `click` listener to it in the `mappingFunction` supplied in the second parameter

In the solution below I showed a simple use case where you can apply this technique to have the click listener added :

```js
(function manageCover() {
  "use strict";
  
  function coverClickHandler(e){
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }

  const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".jacket-left, .jacket-middle, .jacket-right");
  const cover = Array.from(nodeList, (ele) => ele.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler));
})();
```

```html
<div class="jacket-left">jacket-left</div>
<div class="jacket-middle">jacket-middle</div>
<div class="jacket-right">jacket-right</div>
```